# What does "Warning : Parameter can be IComparable" mean in OmniSharp?

Tags: c#, omnisharp

I've just set up Sublime Text and OmniSharp for doing C# development, and I'm suddenly running into this warning a lot. When I write a function with a float as a parameter, it gives this warning.

For example, in a class where `height` is a `float`, this function

```
public void SetHeight(float h) {
    height = h;
}
```

Gives `Warning : Parameter can be IComparable`. The actual C# compiler doesn't warn about it.

What does the error actually mean and how should I resolve it?

Comment: What is the type of `height`?

Comment: @SLaks It's a float, I've edited the question to clarify that.

Comment: That sounds like a bug in their warning, although I'm not sure.

Comment: It's not a warning, it's a coding suggestion and you can ignore it.
I think we should change things to make this clearer. 

If you want to stop the error from displaying, you can edit this file https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-server/blob/master/OmniSharp/config.json#L28-L31

You should be able to find this file inside the omnisharp folder of the sublime plugin folder.

Comment: So, what does it means, @jasoni ?